# TYPO3 error: Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController::getPageRenderer()

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

Getting the error when using the extension ke_serach 2.4.2 in TYPO3 8.7.1.

Please refer the below image for reference.

[image]

Comment: If you have such problem, open a bug report for the extension.

Comment: Okay next time i will keep in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In TYPO3 8 LTS `getPageRenderer()` Methods Deprecated. Now, You can use PageRender Methods like below.

```
$pageRender = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
$pageRender->addJsFooterFile($jsFile, 'text/javascript', true, false, '', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The extension ke_search is not compatible with TYPO3 8LTS yet. You can check the compatibility at the [TER](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ke_search).

The exception is thrown because the extension still calls a method that was first deprecated in TYPO3 7LTS (see [deprecation RST](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/7.6/Changelog/7.4/Deprecation-68074-DeprecateGetPageRenderer.html)) and finally removed in TYPO3 8LTS (see [breaking RST](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.0/Breaking-72424-RemovedDeprecatedTypoScriptFrontendControllerOptionsAndMethods.html)).

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer... And thanks a ton for answering on my question as i found a good thing in my hand that is https://usetypo3.com/ that's your blog from your profile. I am sure it will be more helpful to me In the coming days. Thanks once again. Cheers !!!

Comment: So you got the warning popup in the TYPO3 extension manager that the extension is not compatible, clicked the checkbox that said "*I am able to and will investigate issues myself*" and *then* go whining on stackoverflow because it broke?