# TYPO3 - Load css file on init when extensions gets loaded in 8LTS? getPageRenderer() is depreciated

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I used to load a css file when my extension gets loaded like this in 7LTS:

```
/**
 * Init
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function initializeAction() {

    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getPageRenderer()->addCssFile('typo3conf/ext/myextension/Resources/Public/Css/myextension.css');

}
```

In 8LTS I get an error:

Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController::getPageRenderer()

Supposedly getPageRenderer() is depcreciated:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.0/Breaking-72424-RemovedDeprecatedTypoScriptFrontendControllerOptionsAndMethods.html?highlight=getpagerenderer

How can I load a css file when my extension gets loaded now?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
/**
 * Init
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function initializeAction() {

    $pageRender = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
    $pageRender->addCssFile('typo3conf/ext/myextension/Resources/Public/Css/basic.css');       

}
```

The duplicate link describes an alternative way (via templating) ... but not via an action ... so in my opinion no duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3: How could I add css and js files via controller initialize action and page renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440189/typo3-how-could-i-add-css-and-js-files-via-controller-initialize-action-and-pag)

Comment: Please see [my answer to this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440189/typo3-how-could-i-add-css-and-js-files-via-controller-initialize-action-and-pag/45440378#45440378).

Comment: Oh I didn't see that ... thanks. In meantime I tried to do it in the controller like also described in your link ... would you know why it is not working?

Comment: Why not using `vhs:asset`? (Only using version 7, not sure if vhs:asset is still a way to go in version 8). I use vhs:asset to merge some CSS files together. And to load some other CSS files only when I use a specific template/plugin

Comment: @nbar because it would be nice to solve such things in a controller, rather then in a template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PageRenderer itself is **not** deprecated, just the method `->getPageRenderer()` as the PageRenderer is now a Singleton.

So what you do is
`$pageRenderer = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);` and you are fine.