# TYPO3: Load section FooterAssets in createAction() of a fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I am loading some additional Javascript in the template of the `newAction()` of my controller:

Templates/Controller/New.html

```
<f:section name="FooterAssets">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        // do something
    });
</f:section>
```

This works perfectly fine, but as soon as an error occurs when I save the record, the  `FooterAssets` assets are not loaded anymore. So somehow the `createAction()` does not load/add the `FooterAssets`.

Is there a way to load the `FooterAssets` if an error occurs when saving a record?

And a more general question:

Are the `HeaderAssets` and `FooterAssets` the recomended way to include specific Javascript or CSS for an controller action?

Comment: May this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440189/typo3-how-could-i-add-css-and-js-files-via-controller-initialize-action-and-pag

Comment: @gautamsinhmori I think, I am doing exactly, what they do, or am I missing something? But my questions is about loading the `FooterAssets` in the `createAction()` which has no template itself.

Comment: How do you want to load JavaScript/jQuery without any template? What do you want to achieve with JS in your `createAction()` ?

Comment: @gautamsinhmori My problem occurs, when I create a new record, but the validation fails. In this case the `FooterAssets` of the template `New.html` are not loaded. So initially loading the `NewAction()` works perfectly fine, but submitting a form which does not validate, will not load the `FooterAssets` anymore.