# Load specific style sheet for each frontend plugin - TYPO3 Extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

Using TYPO3 version 8

I have a custom extension that contains three frontend plugins.

For each of the three plugins I have a separate stylesheet for each of them.

Currently, all three style sheets are loaded even if one of the plugins isn't loaded on that page.

My setup.ts:

```
page.includeCSS.tx_myextension_frontendpluginONE = EXT:myextension/Resources/Public/Css/frontendpluginONE.css
page.includeCSS.tx_myextension_frontendpluginTWO = EXT:myextension/Resources/Public/Css/frontendpluginTWO.css
page.includeCSS.tx_myextension_frontendpluginTHREE = EXT:myextension/Resources/Public/Css/frontendpluginTHREE.css
```

Question:

**Using only Typoscript**, can I load a stylesheet for each plugin and not have it load if the plugin is not displayed on the page? I assumed it would sit somewhere in my extension configuration:

```
plugin.tx_myextension_frontendpluginONE.settings {
 Call it in here perhaps?
}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3: How could I add css and js files via controller initialize action and page renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440189/typo3-how-could-i-add-css-and-js-files-via-controller-initialize-action-and-pag)

Comment: "Question:Using Typoscript, can I load a stylesheet for each plugin"

Comment: Yes, and the easier solution is using the `*Assets` sections in your template.