# How can we add javascript file to the front-end of typo3 from extensions

Tags: javascript, typo3

I just wanna add my javascript file to be added while rendering the all front-end pages not the back-end pages. I have tried :

```php
if (TYPO3_MODE=="FE" )   {
   $pageRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
   $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('EXT:eyebase/Resources/Public/JavaScript/testinjectEyebaseJS.js','code');
}
```

but this code added my js file within the CDATA like:-

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
/*RequireJS-Module-EXT:eyebase/Resources/Public/JavaScript/testinjectEyebaseJS.jse6fb06210fafc02fd7479ddbed2d042cc3a5155e*/
require(["EXT:eyebase/Resources/Public/JavaScript/testinjectEyebaseJS.js"], code);

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Please guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the problem to make it by `TypoScript`? Why you want to do it by PHP?

Comment: RequireJS is usually used in the backend only. You can use it in the frontend too but setup is completely up to you then without any standards by TYPO3.

Answer (score 2):

You can add CSS/JS via [HeaderAssets and FooterAssets sections](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79409-AutorenderAssetSectionsInFluidTemplateWithController.html) in your Fluid template.

See [TYPO3: How could I add css and js files via controller initialize action and page renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440189/typo3-how-could-i-add-css-and-js-files-via-controller-initialize-action-and-pag)

Answer (score 0):

You would put this into TypoScript ("setup" part):

```
page {
  includeJS {
    testinjectEyebaseJS = EXT:eyebase/Resources/Public/JavaScript/testinjectEyebaseJS.js
  }
}
```

Have a look for the options here https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#includejs-array.

Comment: Thanks For your reply Jonas ,
But my extension is for Backend and I tried to Make all the required files for TypoScript but It didn't worked .
I followed the following file structure:-

site_package/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php
site_package/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.typoscript
site_package/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript

But it doesn't load my js file for frontend because Bootstrap_Package extension is used for FE. I want to add Js file for all FE pages from my custom extension.
I hope You understood my issue.
Please guide me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will work even with bootstrap_package. Obviously your TypoScript is not loaded. Did you include it on your root page? (Template -> Edit -> Includes in the backend)